# Exim: file lookup condition

Tags: exim

I am have a transport setup in Exim and I which to add a special header for certain users - and for the rest a different header value. I have attempted create the correct syntax for adding this header but are having some problems.

The current code I have is:

```
headers_add = X-SenderTest: {${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/etc/addresses}{header1}{header2}}}
```

So if a $sender_address is in the file /etc/addresses (just a list of new line e-mail addresses) I want the following header:

```
X-SenderTest: header1
```

and for all other $sender_address I want:

```
X-SenderTest: header2
```

However what I actually get is:

```
X-SenderTest: {header1} or 
X-SenderTest: {header2}
```

I have tried multiple combinations of removing the { brackets but without any luck getting a various amount of syntax errors.

For example the following:

```
 X-SenderTest: {${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/etc/probanalogin}Prob no-Prob}}
```

gives this syntax error:

```
failed to expand headers_add or headers_remove: missing or misplaced { or }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you added the header in the transport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the outer brackets. Your line should look like:

```
headers_add = X-SenderTest: ${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/etc/addresses}{header1}{header2}}
```

The extra brackets were being added verbatim to the header.